# Does Cocos2d-x support ETC2 textures?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm building a game and I'm currently supporting the following texture formats:

- ATC
- DXT
- PNG
- PVR

I'd like to add support for ETC2 (ETC1 won't work for us because most of our graphics require an alpha channel). Does Cocos2d-x support ETC2 textures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

But two things.

Cocos2d-x doesn't have ETC2 defines in CCTexture2D.h. You need to add ETC2 defines yourself.

- https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v4-develop/cocos/renderer/CCTexture2D.h#L95-L96
- https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v4-develop/cocos/renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp#L60-L110

  ```
  //! 2-bit PVRTC-compressed texture: PVRTC2 (has alpha channel)
  PVRTC2A,
  //! ETC-compressed texture: ETC
  ETC,
  //! S3TC-compressed texture: S3TC_Dxt1
  S3TC_DXT1,
  ```

And Cocos2d-x uses OpenGL ES 2.0 context, at least, on Android.

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v4-develop/cocos/platform/android/java/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java#L76

```
this.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
```

So using ETC2 for glCompressedTexImage2D needs these extensions.

```
OES_compressed_ETC2_RGB8_texture
OES_compressed_ETC2_sRGB8_texture
OES_compressed_ETC2_punchthroughA_RGBA8_texture
OES_compressed_ETC2_punchthroughA_sRGB8_alpha_texture
OES_compressed_ETC2_RGBA8_texture
OES_compressed_ETC2_sRGB8_alpha8_texture
```